# java regular expression to remove duplicated words

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a problem that removes duplicated words from a string. E.g.,

Input: `Goodbye bye bye world world world`

Output: `Goodbye bye world`

I have got a working pattern from online resources, but I am not able to understand all the content in it.

```
    String pattern = "\\b(\\w+)(\\b\\W+\\b\\1\\b)*";
```

Here is my understanding:

1. the initial `\\b` is to match word bounaries
2. `(\\w+)` matches one or more characters
3. in this expression : `(\\b\\W+\\b\\1\\b)*`

   a. `\\b` matches word boundaries

   b. `\\W+` matches one or more non-word characters

   c. `\\b` again matches a word bounary

   d. `\\1` ??? I dont know what this is for, but it wont work without this

   c. `\\b` again matches for a word bounary

As you can see, my main confusion is about item 3 and especially `\\1`.
Anyone can explain it more clearly?

Comment: Hi. I always use regexr to test and try regular expressions [click here](http://regexr.com/) if you put the pointer over the expressions it shows messages and it explains what is going on

Comment: @GabrielMarques, thanks for the link. However, neither my pattern or the one written by anubhava work in this web editor. Is the syntax the same as java regex?

Comment: yes, try to remove the double back slash character '\' and it wil works. You use double back slashes cause youbare writing the expression in a string and you double it to escape

Comment: @anubhava Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Java you can use a lookahead to remove all the words that have same matched  word ahead using a back-reference:

```
final String regex = "\\b(\\w+)\\b\\s*(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)";
final String input = "Goodbye bye bye world world world\n";

final String result = input.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

It is important to use word boundaries here to avoid matching partial words.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CLTP2j/6)

Comment: It doesn't work if my sentence is 'I work and I sleep' and I expect output as 'I work and sleep'

Comment: Seems we can't achieve this with Regex approach if words are non-consecutive  and we need to write a program. What you say?

Comment: Actually just realized this regex is removing non-consecutive repeats also but it can only only remove all non-last repeats

Comment: @anubhava in other words this _does not work and is wrong_ when the number of matches is odd.

Comment: It works in a way by removing all but last occurrence of the repeating word.