# Regex to replace multiple occurrence of a string in spark dataframe column using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column where a particular string appears multiple times. The number of occurrence is not fixed. I can get such string any number of times.

Example:
Column description has the following data

```
The account account has been cancelled for the account account account and with the account
```

Here basically I want to replace multiple concurrent occurrence of account with single one

Expected Output:

```
The account has been cancelled for the account and with the account
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex pattern (source: [java regular expression to remove duplicated words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813879/java-regular-expression-to-remove-duplicated-words)) with `regexp_replace` to replace duplicate words:

```
val df = spark.sql("select 'The account account has been cancelled for the account account account and with the account' col")

df.show(false)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|The account account has been cancelled for the account account account and with the account|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

val df2 = df.withColumn("col", regexp_replace(col("col"), "\\b(\\w+)(\\b\\W+\\b\\1\\b)*", "$1"))

df2.show(false)
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|The account has been cancelled for the account and with the account|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```